# spacy: how to save the text preprocessed to save time in the future?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have a large collection of papers, and i want to save the result of each

```
doc = nlp(txt)
```

to avoit do the same work in the future and only do the similarity between docs, or for example:

- now i have 5 texts
- i have the similarity bewteen each text (total: 10 similarities)
- i add a new text and i need to know the similarity bewteen the saved documents and the new document, and try to do:

  docToSave = nlp(textToProcess)

NOTE: When i run the before statement, i get the same input text and i think i could have the text after removed stemming, stopwords, lematization, tokenization, etc.

Its posible save the preprocesed text (doc) to save time in the future (save the preprocessed tex) and load this in the future, to could be posible do:

```
SELECT data1 FROM docs;
     doc1 = data1.doc
     SELECT data2 FROM docs WHERE id>data1.id:
          doc2 = data2.doc
          sim = doc1.similarity(doc2)
          saveSimilarity(sim)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `doc.to_bytes()` to serialize the annotations, and then load them back with `doc.from_bytes()`

However for your purpose you should probably just save the `doc.vector`. If you have a lot of pairwise similarities to compute, have a look at an approximate nearest neighbours solution such as the annoy library.